# Removing border lines to all the rows of a first column in ag-grid angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid angular and I have a requirement to show a specific column with icons dynamically based on a condition. I wanted to show this column at 0th position when condition matches as a plain column without border lines.

I tried to do it by using a border:none class in `rowClassRules`, but it is removing the border lines of rows to all the columns which is not my requirement.

I have tried to use the border-none call in the `cellClass` property in colDef. It is only removing the column's right border.

The below is the requirement.

- Based of specific conditions the status column will be displayed with
  an icon which is borderless.

[image]

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cellClassRules property of the column definition to remove the border lines from all the rows of a first column in ag-grid angular.

Example:

```
columnDefs = [{ 
    headerName: 'Column 1', 
    field: 'column1', 
    cellClassRules: { 
        'ag-cell-no-border': true 
    } 
}]
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution , but it is only removing the column border to the right , I also want to remove th border from 4 sides.